# Does Android Library project support native libraries?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, android-native-library

I have read the overview for [Android Library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html). I have in mind to develop an Android project library containing native libraries and JNI wrapper which would be included into the Android project. However, the doc does not explicitly mention if Android library project can include native libraries.

Can anyone confirm/infirm support for native libraries in Android library projects ?

Answer (score 1):

As Android Document said:

> An Android library project is a development project that holds shared
>   Android source code and resources.

An Android Library Project, in fact, isn't so different from normal Android project. You can make a normal android project as library project, except asset folder. They're just different when you declare in `Eclipse Buid Path` or something similar in other IDEs.

Native support simply, just a call to native layer (as in your post, Native Library) such as C/C++ library file (`*.so` file). This function is not specific to Android, but in normal Java project also support this feature: Calling functions from another language inside Java.

So, in short answer, yes :)

Comment: Is this based on you experience also or simply a deduction from the documentation ?